# Negative/positive values with decimals and units

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation, vue.js

I'm looking for an input field which accepts ONLY **negative**/**positive** values with **decimals** and predefined (in an array) **units** at the end of the input.

Sample accepted values are:

```
var inputValue = "150px"; <---- This could be anything (from the input).
var units = ["px", "em", "%"];
var defaultUnit = "px";


100px, 100em, 100%
-100px, -100em, -100%
-100.50px, -100.50em, -100.50%
```

In the end, I need to save the "unit" and the value in variables. If the user didn't provide an unit I then I should assign the default value (px) as the unit.

```
var value = 100;
var unit = %;
```

I can't think of a way to do all these in a **pure javascript** or ES15 way. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex

```js
const rx = /(-?[\d\.]+)(.*)/

//Group 1. optional negative sign, then digits or digits.digits
//Group 2. unit

const data = ['10px', '11.12in', '-4%']

data.forEach(it => {
  const m = rx.exec(it)
  if (m) {
    const parsed = {
      value: parseFloat(m[1]),
      unit: m[2]
    }     
    console.log(it, parsed)
  }
})
```

You can solidify the regex for the number to reject multiple `.` characters, but this is a simple demonstration.  The parseFloat function will catch it, too.

Comment: I would just have the regex as `const rx = /(-?)([\d\.]+)(em|px|%)/` so it also excludes non-valid/expected units.

Comment: I would prefer to check the units in a switch after `eval` so you can report an invalid unit and what it was, or use a default.

Comment: Made few alterations and worked as expected. Thank you @StevenSpungin

https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/phmyj73d/

Comment: @stackminu Nice.  Do a `units.find(it=>it===m[2]) || 'px'` to filter out bad units

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex match operation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) this can be done:

```js
function splitToValueAndUnit(string) {
  if(!string) {
    return { value: "", unit: "px" };
  }
  string = string.toString();
  var value = string.match(/[+-]?\d*[.]?\d*/)[0];
  var unit = string.replace(value, "")
  return {
    value: value,
    unit: unit || "px"
  }
}



console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("123px"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("123%"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("123"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("-123"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("-123px"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit("-123.099%"))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit(""))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit())
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit(123))
console.log(splitToValueAndUnit(undefined))
```

Comment: Awesome. What about some gibberish texts? Then I prefer the unit as "-", and the value as a blank.

Comment: Updated regex to match to -/+ symbol in front of the number and decimal values